# MSBuild error enum does not contain a definition for DataFailed

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm trying to build project in MSBuild version 15 and it gives me this error

> 'ErrorCodeEnum' does not contain a definition for 'ReportDataFailed'

This is where I get this error

```
catch (Exception e)
        {
            ExceptionManager.Publish(e, (int)ErrorCodeEnum.ReportDataFailed);
        }
```

In Visual Studio this project building fine. 
What can be the problem?

Comment: Where is `ErrorCodeEnum` defined?

Comment: ErroCodeEnum defined in another project, which I include via references.